# sortDirection prop of TableCell doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I have a table with items. I use cookies to save them. Also, I have two buttons (increase and decrease). When I press them to change qty it works, but it also puts the item's row to the bottom of the list. I need to keep them in the same position where they are. I used `sortDirection` prop to `TableCell` component to make an order, but it also didn't work. Please help update the code so I can keep items in the same position.
Thanks in advance.

```
export default function CartItemsTable() {
const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies();

function IncreaseQTY(article) {
var newCookie = cookies[article];
newCookie.qty++;
setCookie(article, newCookie, {
  expires: new Date(Date.now() + 604800000),
});
}

function DecreaseQTY(article) {
var newCookie = cookies[article];
newCookie.qty--;
if (newCookie.qty === 0) {
  removeCookie(article);
} else {
  setCookie(article, newCookie, {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 604800000),
  });
}
}

return (
<TableContainer component={Paper}>
  <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} >
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell >Name</TableCell>
        <TableCell sortDirection="asc" align="center">Code</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="center">Price</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="center">QTY</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="center">Total</TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
    <TableBody>
      {Object.keys(cookies).map(function (key, index) {
        return (
          <TableRow
            key={index}
            sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
          >
            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
              {cookies[key].name}
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell  align="center">{cookies[key].article}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center">{cookies[key].price}</TableCell>

            <TableCell align="center">
              <ButtonGroup
                variant="contained"
                aria-label="outlined primary button group"
              >
                <Button
                  onClick={() => {
                    DecreaseQTY(cookies[key].article);
                  }}
                >
                  -
                </Button>
                <Button variant="text" disableRipple={true}>
                  {cookies[key].qty}
                </Button>
                <Button
                  onClick={() => {
                    IncreaseQTY(cookies[key].article);
                  }}
                >
                  +
                </Button>
              </ButtonGroup>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center">
              {cookies[key].qty * cookies[key].price}
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        );
      })}
    </TableBody>
  </Table>
</TableContainer>
);
}
```

**Before I press the button**
[image: Before]

**After I press the increase button, first line went to the bottom**
[image: After]

**Update**

I guess this problem can be occurred because of the cookies order or even related to `react-cookie` package, so I added `console.log(cookies);` to `IncreaseQTY` function. After a couple increasing it starts to show this way

[image: Console]

Comment: Can you show the code for your useCookies hook?  Is it from a library?  If so, which?  Thanks!

Comment: @ckesplin Thanks for your response! `useCookies ` is function of ["react-cookie"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie).